# fabricjs get image after clipping the canvas the set it as new background image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have made a canvas and and added an image to it. It is working like a background image to the canvas. After then I am clipping the canvas to get specific part of the canvas just like cropping. After cropping I want the cropped part and set it as the new background image.

Here is something I have tried but I am unable to set the cropped part as new background image to the canvas. I am getting the same old canvas with clipped part being transparent.

```
function crop(url, name, left, top, width, height, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas')
    var id = "canvas_" + name
    c.id = id
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id)

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {

        oImg.set({
            selectable:false,
        })
        canvas.setDimensions({width:oImg.width, height:oImg.height})
        canvas.add(oImg)
        canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
            ctx.rect(left, top, width, height)
            console.log(ctx)
        };
        canvas.centerObject(oImg)
        canvas.renderAll()
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        console.log(img)
        callback(img)
    }, {crossOrigin: "Anonymous"})
}
```

Here I want my canvas to be returned with cropped area as background Image.

Need help

Comment: Is this some sort of duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083942/fabricjs-set-clipped-object-as-background-to-canvas-after-clipping?  And do you have a jsfiddle?  Also, assuming that the size of the canvas remains the same, it seems like you are trying to use a crop to scale the background image.  Have you tried scaling instead of cropping?